# Sort list of strings alphabetically

Tags: python, list, sorting, cmp, alphabetical-sort

So i have a question, how can i sort this list:

`['Pera','mela','arancia','UVA']`

to be like this:

`['arancia','mela','Pera','UVA']`

In the exercise it said to use the `sorted()` function with the cmp argument.

Comment: `cmp` is deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: Why do you need any argument? Won't that just work if you give it to the sorted function?

Comment: running sorted(myList) will do that for you. You don't the cmp argument

Comment: it will not. it will sort the Uppercase letter words first then the lowercase ones.

Comment: No it has to be sorted alphabeticaly. lowercase or upercase first doesn`t matter. for example: list['Car','amazing','zipcode','Orange']
sorted into: list['amazing','Car','Orange','zipcode']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to sort your elements based lowercase representation of the strings:

```
sorted(['Pera','mela','arancia','UVA'], key=str.lower)
```

this will output:

```
['arancia', 'mela', 'Pera', 'UVA']
```

Comment: Why only the first character?

Comment: It was a mistake actually. The lowercase representation is enough @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Answer (score 6):

You can easily do that, using the `key` argument:

```
my_list = ['Pera','mela','arancia','UVA']
my_list.sort(key=str.lower)
```

Which will get your lowercases chars first.

This will change the object in-place and `my_list` will be sorted.

You can use `sorted` function with the same `key` argument as well, if you want to have a new list. For example:

```
my_list = ['Pera','mela','arancia','UVA']
my_sorted_list = sorted(my_list,key=str.lower)
```

Output will be:

```
>>> my_list
['Pera','mela','arancia','UVA']
>>> my_sorted_list
['arancia', 'mela', 'Pera', 'UVA']
```

Comment: Good answer. Can also note that `sorted` can use the same key if desired.

Comment: Can you please provide the output of this answer?

Comment: `list` methods operate in-place.

Comment: I don`t need lowercase first. just to sort alphabeticaly without considering lowercase or uppercase... ['Car','amazing','zipcode','Orange'] into ['amazing','Car','Orange','zipcode']

Comment: ['Car','amazing','zipcode','Orange'] into ['amazing','Car','Orange','zipcode'] sry for my english. it coused confusion. i need this. hope its more understandeble

Comment: We understand what you want. This accomplishes that goal.

Comment: Yep it does :D sry and ty

Answer (score 4):

Use `sorted()` with a key.

```
>>> mc = ['Pera','mela','arancia','UVA']
>>> sorted(mc, key=str.lower)
['arancia', 'mela', 'Pera', 'UVA']
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help you:

```
>>> words = ['Pera','mela','arancia','UVA']
>>> sorted(words)
['Pera', 'UVA', 'arancia', 'mela']
>>> sorted(words, key=str.swapcase)
['arancia', 'mela', 'Pera', 'UVA']
```

Hope this helps